# find command to find files and concatenate them

Tags: linux, bash, find, cat

I am trying to find all the files of type `*.gz` and `cat` them to `total.gz` and I think I am quite close on this.

This is the command I am using to list all `*.gz`files:

```
find /home/downloaded/. -maxdepth 3 -type d \( ! -name . \) \
    -exec bash -c "ls -ltr '{}' "  \
```

How to modify it so that it will concatenate all of them and write to `~/total.gz`

Directory structure under `downloaded` is as follows

```
/downloaded/wllogs/303/07252014/SysteOut.gz
/downloaded/wllogs/301/07252014/SystemOut_13.gz
/downloaded/wllogs/302/07252014/SystemOut_14.gz
```

Comment: Your `find` invocation seems a bit convoluted. Wouldn't `find /home/downloaded/. -maxdepth 3 -type f -name "*.gz" -print0 | xargs -0 cat > total.gz` be a better aproach? (or, alternatively, assuming GNU `find` : `find /home/downloaded/. -maxdepth 3 -type f -name "*.gz" -exec cat {} + > total.gz`)

Comment: Yes, you are right. This find was snippet from the my code and I was trying to modify to work for this task. BTW what does it "+" mean

Comment: The `+` is a GNU `find` extension that allows it to `-exec` the given command with multiple arguments, rather than the one-at-a-time you would get with `-exec cat {} \;`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `cat` in `-exec` and redirect output of `find`:

```
find /home/downloaded/ -type f -name '*.gz' -exec cat {} \; > output
```

Comment: It did not work, it says downloaded/./wllogs/301/07172014 : Is a directory
. Did I miss anything in ques?

Comment: I would expect `-type f` (Didn't realized that you used -type d)

Comment: I tried with f but the output file size is zero. so it did not work either.

Comment: No luck this time too. Just a observation - When I tried with -type d and ls command it did show all the directories and files. and with type f nothing comes up

Comment: @ hek2mgl : Awesome, I tried with maxdepth 4 and it did show files. IT worked ! Thank you for time

Comment: `-maxdepth 4` would have been the next thing that I would have suggested. (As the path to tgz'S contains 4 and not 3 components). However, if there aren't gzips located in folders nested deeper than 4, I would just skip. (this would speedup the find process)

Comment: Yes, This indeed speed up,

Comment: find . -name *.gz > /tmp/1.txt This command gave me the expected output

Answer (score 0):

Use `echo` in `-exec` and redirect the output:

```
find /home/downloaded/ -name "*.gz" -exec echo {} \; > output
```

Comment: As commented by a new user (in a non-answer which will probably be deleted), `echo` merely outputs the file names themselves, which is not what the OP is asking about.