# Bash: find and concatenate files

Tags: bash, csv

I have the following structure:

```
/home/
├── DIR1/
│   └── file_ab.csv
├── DIR2/
│   └── file_cd.csv
└── DIR3/
    └── file3_ef.csv
```

Where `file_**.csv` contains rows of floats, different floats for each DIR.

I want to grab the contents of all of the `file_**.csv` files and concatenate them.

I found this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25083335/find-command-to-find-files-and-concatenate-them):

```
find /home -type f -name '*.csv' -exec cat {} \; > pl_parameters
```

But I get an empty file called 'pl_parameters'. Why is the file empty? How can I fix this?

Comment: Why not just use `cat /home/*/file1.csv > pl_parameters`

Comment: I tried a modified version of your suggestion: `cat /home/*/*.csv > pl_parameters` but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find /home/DIR* -name 'file*csv' |xargs cat > output.csv
```

`find /home/DIR* -name '*csv'` gives you the files absolute paths.

`xargs cat` will iterate the files and `cat` print the files content

Comment: Can I use the pwd instead of 'home' somehow?

Comment: `find $(pwd)/DIR* -name '*csv'`

Comment: The final working version, since I had only one csv file per directory, was:

`find $(pwd)/RUN* -name '*csv' |xargs cat > pl_paras_means.csv`

Comment: @StatsSorceress check Karthick's comment, it's helpful!

Answer (score 0):

With Bash 4.0+, you can use `globstar` and use a more straight forward command:

```
shopt -s globstar
cd /home
cat **/*.csv > pl_parameters
```

`**/` expands to the entire directory tree underneath the current directory.

---

Your command:

```
find /home -type f -name '*.csv' -exec cat {} \; > pl_parameters
```

looks good to me - not sure why you got a zero by output file.