# Bash: find and concatenate filenames with two digits

Tags: regex, bash

I'm trying to find all instances of csv files in a set of directories and concatenate them into one csv file.

The catch is that the directories are numbered. I only want directories that end in two digits. For example, I want directories RUN11, RUN12, etc, but not RUN1, RUN2.

If I didn't care about having two-digit numbers, I'd do this (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42210337/bash-find-and-concatenate-files))

```
find $(pwd)/RUN* -name '*csv' |xargs cat > big_cat_file.csv
```

I tried this:

```
find $(pwd)/RUN[!0-9]{2} -name '*csv' |xargs cat > big_cat_file.csv
```

But it says no such file or directory.

How can I grab csv files from directories with names like RUN11, RUN12, but not RUN1, RUN2?

Comment: You are mixing globbing and regular expressions.  `[!0-9]` is globbing (`[^0-9]` in RE), and `{2}` is a regular expression quantifier not available in globbing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to use regular expression syntax where you need to use a glob.

You just need to specify the range twice, rather than using `{2}`:

```
find "$PWD"/RUN[0-9][0-9] -name '*csv' |xargs cat > big_cat_file.csv
```

(Note that `[!0-9]` matches any single character *except* a digit.)

To accommodate any legal filename that might match `*csv`, you should use the `-exec` primary instead of `xargs`. (Consider what would happen if a file name contains whitespace, or in the worst case, a newline.)

```
    find "$PWD"/RUN[0-9][0-9] -name '*csv' -exec cat {} + > big_cat_file.csv
```

This not only works with any valid file name, but minimizes the number of calls to `cat` that are required.