# Reading files from child directories of path and appending them to one file

Tags: linux, shell

I have a folder with 20 subfolders each of them containing one file.I want to read all the 20 files from the subfolders and append them to another file.
What should i do for this? Is there any awk commands for this?
Either a python/perl script or linux command will be very useful

Comment: This is very doable in almost any language. I suggest you split this all up in to steps and figure out how to do each of these things in the language you choose. Based on what you have listed, I suggest doing it in Python. It will be easier to write.

Comment: with the windows shell it is super easy, it must be with the linux one too. Python is an overkill imho.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25083335/find-command-to-find-files-and-concatenate-them                                                          https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42210337/bash-find-and-concatenate-files?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I would disagree about the Python overkill, but yeah, it's doable/easy in anything.

Comment: `cat file1 file2 file3 > dest_file`

Comment: Don't spam language tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way for this would be probably (unless you need some more information than the content of the files):

```
cat <directory>/*/* >> <resulting_file>
```

Comment: I hate this kind of answers. Without a proper example, a newbie will just lose himself. It would be nice to format the answer with a real example,  in this manner: `Let's assume we have a folder at path : D:\my_folder, which has 2 folders, 2 files... blah, blah... For this folder, to get the desired result, the command would be : cat D:\my_folder ...`

Answer (score 0):

Make use of find command, using which you have a privilege to restrict the directory path/file types, modification times, etc.
find command used to search recursively by default (i.e) it starts from the directory till the last child of the tree.

In your case, I assume you are looking for just any files. you can do as below.

```
find <PATH from where to search> -type f > log file # adding filters that you are looking for files.
Ex: find /users/hero/parent -type f > listoffiles.log
```

If you are looking for any specific type of file, like log files (or) c files, etc. you can add filters like below.

```
find /path -type f -name *.log > listoflogfiles
```

*Note: By default, find do recursive search.* 
Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Using python(3) you can use the following code:
It first opens the new target_file and then opens each source_file and writes it's content to the target_file.

```
import os

path_with_subdirs = '/dir/with/subdirectories'

source_files = [os.path.join(dp, f) for dp, dn, filenames in os.walk(path_with_subdirs) for f in filenames]

target_file = '/target/location/output_file.txt'

with open(target_file, 'w') as target:
    for source_file in source_files:
        with open(source_file, 'r') as source:
            [target.write(line) for line in source]
```